# R: How to perform mathematical operations on two numerical vectors?

Tags: r, lapply

I want to calculate `length` as `end` minus `start` plus `one`. My code below did not apply the "plus one" but I wanted to show the code that's causing my terminal to crash. `end` and `start` are both numeric vectors derived from the `dat` dataframe.

```
start <- as.numeric(dat$Locus)
end <- as.numeric(start + nchar(dat$Read_Sequence))
length <- lapply(end, '-', start)   # Must Plus one
```

The `lapply` function keeps causing my linux terminal to crash.

```
> dput(dat[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(Read_Name = c(">FC305JN_20080525:1:94:969:1769",
">FC305JN_20080525:1:94:967:1768", ">FC305JN_20080525:1:68:1789:1534",
">FC305JN_20080525:1:68:1790:1537", ">FC305JN_20080525:1:46:737:1543"
), Read_Sequence = c("TCCTGAATTTGCCATTCAAGAAGTGTTA", "TCCTGAATTTGCCATTCAAGAAGTGTTA",
"GGAAAGCTGGGCAATTTCCCTCCTCCGC", "GGAAAGCTGGGCAATTTAACTCCTCCGA",
"GTCGATGCTGCCCTGAGTTGTCCCAAAG"), Chromosome = c("chr6.fa", "chr6.fa",
"chr6.fa", "chr6.fa", "chr6.fa"), Locus = c(82635L, 82635L, 90582L,
90582L, 93026L), Strand = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F")), row.names = c(153233L,
154656L, 106393L, 106484L, 65943L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why not just do `end - start + 1` or if it should be a loop, `Map("-", end, start + 1)`

Comment: This example isn't reproducible. As @akrun says, I don't think `lapply(end, '-', start)` is actually what you want to do (it subtracts *all* of the start values from *each* end value, rather than subtracting each start value from the corresponding end value ...

Comment: But if `start=Locus` and `end=start+nchar(Read_Sequence)` then end-start+1 is just `nchar(Read_Sequence)+1`. Why not just calculate that directly?

Comment: Neither `end - start + 1` nor `nchar(Read_Sequence)+1` give me what I want because both give me the same value for the entire vector. What I want is to calculate `end-start+1` for each corresponding sets of `start` and `end` values.

Comment: This doesn’t make sense yet. What is the desired output for the sample data you provided? This will allow us to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @melolili - `end - start + 1` **is** calculating the difference between each corresponding value of `end` and `start`. In the example data you have, the differences are all `28` (29 with the + 1). Proof of what the code does - `end <- 1:10; start <- 10:1; end - start`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this? It will add an `end` column with each start + the length of that sequence, and then length is the difference plus 1, or one more than the number of characters.

```
dat$start = as.numeric(dat$Locus)
dat$end = dat$start + nchar(dat$Read_Sequence)
dat$length = dat$end - dat$start + 1
#alteratively
#dat$end = nchar(dat$Read_Sequence) + 1
```